# How to only enable error logging if in production environment?

Tags: angular, sentry

I have an Angular 5 application with error logging using sentry.io which uses raven.js.

I have this all working correctly but do not want to log errors when running in development. How do I only enable error logging when production mode is enabled?

I have the following in my app.module.ts

```
import * as Raven from 'raven-js';

Raven
  .config('https://xxx@sentry.io/xxx')
  .install();

export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: any): void {
    Raven.captureException(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using angular-cli, they have `environment` files you can simply do `if (environment.production)`

Comment: @penleychan That worked perfectly, thanks friend! Want to post this as an answer so I can mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli, they have environment files you can simply do

`if (environment.production) { ... }`

Answer (score 7):

I thought it worth sharing as I had a similar issue where I wanted to ...

- use my Sentry.io errorHandler only in production
- use Angular default ErrorHandler in dev
- inject dependencies into the handler

**app.error-handler.ts**

First step is to implement a factory provider function to return either `SentryErrorHanddler` or  Angular default `ErrorHandler` based on `environment.production` property and receiving needed dependency as a parameter.

```js
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export function errorHandlerFactory(toastService: ToastService) {
  if (environment.production) {
    return new SentryErrorHandler(toastService);
  }
  return new ErrorHandler();
}
```

Second step is to implement `SentryErrorHandler` class that will receive the dependency into the constructor *(note that I don't prefix the class with @Injectable decorator because It will be instantiated by the factory above and not injected by the DI)*.

```js
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(public toastService: ToastService) {
    Sentry.init({
      dsn: 'https://<YOUR-SENTRY-KEY>@sentry.io/<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>',
    });
  }

  handleError(error: any) {
    Sentry.captureException(error.originalError || error);
    this.toastService.show('An error occurs, please try again later.');
    throw error;
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

Finally, in the `AppModule` provide `ErrorHandler` with the implemented factory provider `errorHandlerFactory` and specify it needs some injection dependency through `deps` property which is going to be pass as a parameter to the factory provider function

```js
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { errorHandlerFactory } from './app.error-handler';

@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useFactory: errorHandlerFactory, deps: [ToastService] },
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note that everything related to `ToastService` is only as an example to represent an external dependency you would like to access into your custom handler.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was using the old Sentry.io SDK and only recently upgraded to the method described in your answer. This question was mainly surrounding Angular environments as opposed to sentry.io but thanks for your response!

Comment: My use-case was with Sentry.io but it can be applied to anything related to providing custom ErrorHandler or fallbacking to Angular ErrorHandler depending on environment configuration ... I put it there if anybody else end up here, not expecting to be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Really great answer! I was trying to only load Airbrake in production, but wasn't aware you could use a factory inside AppModule. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use  function [`isDevMode`](https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode)

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log(isDevMode());
  }
}
```

if its not returning true, it should be prod

Comment: Are there any benefits to this over penleychan's solution?

Comment: well this is from angular core, while environment is from angular cli. the first one is recommended over the later

Comment: while that may be the case the other answer better suits my use case since I am using the angular-cli but thanks for your help!